# Printing to Intermec Printers via CITRIX

Tags: printing, citrix, sap, intermec

We are looking to print to Intermec label printers (attached locally to PC's) from an SAP system to printers within a CITRIX environment.

Please can you tell me if the Citrix Universal Print Server and Citrix XenApp Client both work with the Intermec Printer Language (IPL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the needed driver within your XenApp farm. If the redirection is correctly done the receiver will bring the printer correctly to the xenapp server. If the server does not recognize the driver then it will map the citrix universal driver. No worry there as you can create rule within xenapp that if a printer x is mapped, you replace it with driver y.

So you got a lot of options to make it work